# Magento wrong item price

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get the regular price of an item including VAT using:

```
$unitPrice = round($item->getPrice(), 2);
```

It gives me a `.01` difference.

I also tried without rounding off - still `.01` difference. It returns `16.06` or `16.04` for the price `16.05`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in Magento you use the built in currency formatting methods rather than PHP's `round`, for example:

```
$unitPrice = Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($item->getPrice(), false);    // $50.00
```

This will return a *display* price like `$50.00`. If you just want the raw value, use this instead:

```
$unitPrice = Mage::app()->getStore()->roundPrice($item->getPrice()); // 50.0
```

Note that `Mage_Core_Model_Store::roundPrice` is essentially just a wrapper for what you're doing already, but it's safer to use because it's bundled into the Magento framework.

Also - you didn't mention which Magento version you're using, but if it's lower than 1.8 you might be seeing [a delta rounding issue as noted here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15846/why-does-magento-store-a-rounding-delta-when-calculating-taxes). It's resolved from 1.8 on.